# Kali Linux 2019 why I see Ubuntu?

Tags: linux

```
root@Msys:~# sudo apt-get update               
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise InRelease                       
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release [49.6 kB]    
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release.gpg [198 B]
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release.gpg
Hit:7 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Hit:8 http://kali.download/kali kali-bleeding-edge InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
root@Msys:~#
```

Comment: That is Ubuntu 12.04 which support ended in April 2017.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list`? Please edit your question and do not respond in the comments!

Comment: Please use complete sentences in title and description. Also in you edit include whether you used Kali or other distros before.

Comment: Just a guess that some of the tools bundled with Kali come from the Ubuntu repository.  It could be that one or more tools hasn't needed updating in a long time, and the Kali maintainers continued to pull it from an old version of Ubuntu.  With that Ubuntu release now long out of support, the keys may be out of date.

Comment: @fixer1234 The repositories no longer exist. Contents have been moved to archive, "old-releases".

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, it sounds like you have the explanation.  How about posting the solution to the problem as an answer?

Comment: @fixer1234 No, I don't LOL. All I can see is "precise" repositories that, of course, will give that error in 2019. And this is where it ends. I don't know why they're there, I don't know Kali therefore I don't know how it's supposed o look like, etc. But if the OP doesn't know either, they shouldn't be using Kali, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing Ubuntu repositories referenced because Kali is simply a very customized version of Ubuntu.

Comment: This is wrong as Kali is based off Debian testing (codename Buster for the moment). Ubuntu is based on Debian stable release (codename Stretch for the moment). This is an important distinction as Ubuntu has features Debian has not and are therefore only available in Ubuntu based distros.

Comment: @NordlysJeger, Ubuntu is based on Debian Unstable.  Some of the testing and bug reports from Ubuntu feed Debian in creating Debian Stable.

Comment: @fixer1234 thank you, I didn't know that.